# Convert the key of a dictionary into a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I think that the problem of my code is that each time the loop in iterating on a new variable, the previous variable is not deleted. So I end up with plot that contains all the previous data coming from the previous iterations. 
What I may need is a function to clear up the memory at the end of each loop... 
The reason while I originally asked this question, was that I run the same loop over and over and I end up having to many data on my plot (since it seems like the data are not clear at the end of each iteration).

```
dicohist = {
'couts-formels': dftotal.total_cout_formels,
'couts_direct': dftotal.cout_total,
'perte-de-prod': dftotal.snt_prix
}

for key in dicohist:
    histo = Series.hist(dicohist[key],bins=50)  
    histo.set_xlabel("cout en euros")
    histo.set_ylabel("nombre de sujets")
    histo.set_title(key)
    fig = histo.get_figure()
    fig.savefig('/Users/Salim/Desktop/plot/%s.png'%(key))
```

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: Those are already strings

Comment: my error message is "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)". Yes my keys are strings, but when I am calling them in my loop they are not considered as strings...

Comment: Then your example code is not representative of your actual problem, because the keys you show here are pure ASCII. Please update it with your error message and the actual key strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a pyplot function :  plt.close() at the end of my loop which solved the problem